# how to pass the image using storyboard in ios7

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, uistoryboardsegue

I cant able to pass the image from 1 view to another view in ios7.

in current view

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
BehindContributors *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
[destViewController setImage:@"1.jpg"];
}
```

in destination view

```
    self.image1.image=self.image;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try `imageNamed` method on `ÙIImage`

like so;

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
      BehindContributors *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
   [destViewController setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"]];
}
```

Comment: @user3427653 we have a ritual in stackoverflow. We accept answers that help. check button on the left of answer and below arrow. :)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to pass image name(i.e. NSString object) or image itself(i.e. UIImage object).

**If you are passing image name then use following**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        BehindContributors *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        [destViewController setImageName:@"1.jpg"];
    }
}
```

Destination view should have property *imageName* of NSString type
then use it as

```
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageName:imageName];
```

**If you are passing image then use following**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        BehindContributors *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        [destViewController setImageData:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"]];
    }
}
```

Destination view should have property *imageData* of UIImage type
then use it as

```
self.imageView.image = imageData;
```